# Time synchronisation with Ubuntu guest and Hyper-V Client (Windows 8)

Tags: sync, time, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu Server installed (quantal, 12.10, 32-bit), as a VM guest using Hyper-V with Windows 8.

Note I am using this on my laptop. When I re-open my laptop, the time is no longer synchronised with the VM.

How often does the time synchronisation process take? Is it possible to enforce it somehow?

I can see the following modules installed on Ubuntu:
 * hv_storvsc
 * hv_netvsc
 * hv_utils
 * hv_vmbus

I have time sync checked under "Synchronistaion services" in Hyper-V.

Note I don't want my VM to require internet access, so unfortunately using an Internet date sync server will not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install Microsoft's Linux Integration Services on the VM you are having issues with.

- Downloading the Linux Integration Components v2.1
- Mount the ISO in the VM
- Run these commands as root under the VM:

---

```
mkdir /mnt/cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
mkdir /linuxic
cp –R /mnt/cdrom/* /linuxic
cd /linuxic/
make
make install
```

- Reboot the VM
- Run this command under the VM as root to verify it worked

  `/sbin/lsmod | grep vsc`

Source: [Installing Linux Integration Services v2.1 Hyper-V R2 On CentOS 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20130209123406/http://blog.nlitee.com/virtualization/hyper-v/installing-linux-integration-services-v2-1-hyper-v-r2-on-centos-5/) (courtesy of the [Internet archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/)).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Installing and Activating Hyper-V Linux Integration Services](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/installing-and-activating-hyper-v-linux-integration-services.html), Ubuntu has included Ubuntu Hyper-V Integration Services since 12.04.  The article lists the steps to activate these services:

> 1. The first step is to edit the "modules" file located in
>      /etc/initramfs-tools using this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo vi /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
>    ```
> 2. In vi Editor, navigate to the last line in the file and use the
>      insert (I) command to append and enter the following lines:
>
>    ```
>    hv_vmbus
>    hv_storvsc
>    hv_blkvsc
>    hv_netvsc
>    ```
> 3. Save the file by hitting the Esc key and then issuing the ":x" command
> 4. Next, run the following command to re-initialize the "modules" file:
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-initramfs –u
>    ```
> 5. Finally, reboot the virtual machine by executing the below command in Shell:
>
>    ```
>    sudo shutdown -r now
>    ```
>
>    Once the guest virtual machine is rebooted, the LIS drivers and services will be registered in the system.

Comment: I just realized that my answer doesn't really answer the original question.  I mistakenly read the first answer and assumed that it fully answered the question.  Next time, I'll read the question more carefully.

Comment: Why do you say your answer doesn't really answer the original (my) question? Seems like you attempt to provide a relevant answer here. I am still struggling with stalling datetime on the guest, all the modules you have mentioned are loaded (`hv_*`). NTP is uninstalled, per Microsofts recommendation. Keep in mind this is Debian, not Ubuntu (which I understand is a Debian derivative).

Answer (score 0):

I think [Time Synchronization in Hyper-V](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/11/19/time-synchronization-in-hyper-v/) may answer your questions.